# Magento 2: Add password strength meter in custom form

Tags: magento2

Hello i have created custom form in which i need to add password strength meter, i just copy the customer form as my custom registration form but password strength meter not work how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code after the password field.

```
<div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
        <!--?= $block--->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
            <!--?= $block--->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</div> 


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".field.password": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-login"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please keep in mind, that you need to use the ID or the form element class for the formSelector here. In our case the form selector is ‘form-login’, and that is why we used form.form-login here.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot its working for me

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers!!!

Comment: @Sumit, is this code for custom form? looks like its added for login form, can we add this one for the form which has password field and confirm password field? with all the default validations

Comment: @jafarpinjar I'm not sure about the same. You can try it in your custom form it should work. :)

Comment: @Sumit, Yes i have tried it, but not working for me, I have 2 fields, password and confirm password, it should work like default customer register form

Comment: @jafarpinjar OK, I'm not sure about its working with custom form because I've not used it yet in any custom form.

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <div class="field password required" data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?>"
                   class="input-text"
                   placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password*') ?>"
                   data-password-min-length="8"
                   data-password-min-character-sets="3"
                   data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                   autocomplete="off">
            <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" >
                <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password Strength'); ?>:
                    <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label" >
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No Password'); ?>
                                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```